# Sitecore upgradation from 7.2 to 9.0

Tags: upgrade

I have used express miration tool from 7.2 instance to 9.0 instance excluding bin folder.

As bin folder have sitecore and application dll's which are many.

Can someone give me idea how to migrate the bin without affecting new sitecore dll's?

Comment: Why would you exclude the bin folder?

Comment: It was excluded by default in tool default.config file so i assumed we have to do that manually else it might overwrite sitecore 9 dll's.  Then I will try removing that config and migrate bin folder as well

Comment: Shouldn't you migrate to a clean 9 environment and after migration publish your (updated) code on it?

Comment: Unless you have any customization in Sitecore Dlls on 7.2, you can take the Dlls from clean Sitecore 9 instance and then try building your solution. I would prefer to use Nuget for my upgraded solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find source code of all the dlls in your project which are referencing sitecore Previous version class libraries and update the references of those projects with the new dlls and build it to make sure it is successful.publish those projects with the newly compiled sitecore dlls on to the new instance of sitecore.

You might need to change some API calls of sitecore in this process.